# Is there a way to emulate linear types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, linear-types

I am modeling a system that has an operation that creates a resource and other operations that consume that resource. However, a given resource can only be consumed once - is there a way that I can guarantee that at compile time?

For concreteness, lets say the first operation bakes a cake and that there are two other operations, one for "choosing to eat" the cake and one for "choosing to have the cake" and that I can only do one or the other.

```
-- This is my current "weakly typed" interface:
bake :: IO Cake
eat  :: Cake -> IO ()
keep :: Cake -> IO ()

-- This is OK
do
  brownie <- bake
  muffin <- bake
  eat brownie
  keep muffin

-- Eating and having the same cake is not OK:
do
  brownie <- bake
  eat brownie
  keep brownie -- oops! already eaten!
```

Its easy to enforce the restriction of not keeping an already eaten cake (or vice versa) at runtime by setting an flag on the cake after we use it. But is there a way to enforce this at compile time?

BTW, this question is meant for a proof of concept so I am OK with any black magic that can give me the static safety I want.

Comment: Could you use phantom types to indicate wether a cake has been eaten - like `data Cake a = Cake` and `data Eaten`, `data Fresh` then `bake = Cake :: Cake Fresh` and `eat :: Cake Fresh -> Cake Eaten; eat Cake = Cake`?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Sure, but if you then did `eatenCookie <- uneatenCookie`, nothing would stop you from using `uneatenCookie` afterwards.

Comment: I see - thus you would need to write your own version of `<-` that takes care of clearing `uneatenCookie`, but I think that is beyond my haskpertise.

Comment: Possibly useful: [Embedding a Full Linear Lambda Calculus in Haskell](http://functorial.com/Embedding-a-Full-Linear-Lambda-Calculus-in-Haskell/linearlam.pdf). I've seen another paper with a similar approach, but I'm having trouble finding it now...

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/Kitchen.agda) is a naive way to do this in Agda.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Haskell, a basic version of this could be expressed with a GADT indexed by a store of cakes (represented by a list of `Nat`-s):

```
{-# LANGUAGE
  TypeFamilies, GADTs, TypeOperators, PartialTypeSignatures,
  DataKinds, PolyKinds #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy
import GHC.Exts

-- Allocate a new cake
type family New cs where
  New '[]       = 0
  New (c ': cs) = c + 1

-- Constraint satisfiable if "c" is in "cs"
type family Elem c cs :: Constraint where
  Elem c (c ': cs)  = ()
  Elem c (c' ': cs) = Elem c cs

type family Remove c cs where
  Remove c '[]        = '[]  
  Remove c (c ': cs)  = cs
  Remove c (c' ': cs) = c' ': Remove c cs

data Bake :: [Nat] -> [Nat] -> * -> * where
  Pure :: a -> Bake cs cs a
  Bake :: (Proxy (New cs) -> Bake (New cs ': cs) cs' a) -> Bake cs cs' a
  Eat  :: Elem c cs => Proxy c -> Bake (Remove c cs) cs' a -> Bake cs cs' a
  Keep :: Elem c cs => Proxy c -> Bake cs cs' a -> Bake cs cs' a

ok :: Bake '[] _ _
ok =
  Bake $ \cake1 ->
  Bake $ \cake2 ->
  Eat cake1 $
  Keep cake2 $
  Eat cake2 $
  Pure ()

not_ok :: Bake '[] _ _
not_ok =
  Bake $ \cake1 ->
  Bake $ \cake2 ->
  Eat cake1 $
  Keep cake1 $ -- we already ate that
  Eat cake2 $
  Pure ()
```

Unfortunately we can't remove the type annotations from `Bake` actions and leave types to be inferred:

```
foo =
  Bake $ \cake1 ->
  Bake $ \cake2 ->
  Eat cake1 $
  Pure ()

-- Error: Could not deduce (Elem (New cs0) (New cs0 + 1 : New cs0 : cs0))
```

Obviously, `(Elem (New cs0) (New cs0 + 1 : New cs0 : cs0))` is satisfiable for all `cs0`, but GHC can't see this, because it cannot decide whether `New cs0` is inequal to `New cs0 + 1`, because GHC can't assume anything about the flexible `cs0` variable.

If we add `NoMonomorphismRestriction`, `foo` would typecheck, but that would make even incorrect programs typecheck by pushing all the `Elem` constraints to the top. This would still prevent doing anything useful with incorrect terms though, but it's a rather ugly solution.

---

More generally, we can express `Bake` as an indexed free monad, which gets us `do`-notation with `RebindableSyntax`, and allows a definition for `BakeF` that is somewhat clearer than what we've seen before. It could also reduce boilerplate much like the plain old `Free` monad, although I find it rather unlikely that people would find use for indexed free monads on two different occasions in practical code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE
  TypeFamilies, GADTs, TypeOperators, PartialTypeSignatures, StandaloneDeriving,
  DataKinds, PolyKinds, NoImplicitPrelude, RebindableSyntax, DeriveFunctor #-}

import Prelude hiding (Monad(..))
import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy
import GHC.Exts

class IxFunctor f where
  imap :: (a -> b) -> f i j a -> f i j b

class IxFunctor m => IxMonad m where
  return :: a -> m i i a
  (>>=)  :: m i j a -> (a -> m j k b) -> m i k b
  fail   :: String -> m i j a

infixl 1 >>
infixl 1 >>=

(>>) :: IxMonad m => m i j a -> m j k b -> m i k b
ma >> mb = ma >>= const mb

data IxFree f i j a where
  Pure :: a -> IxFree f i i a
  Free :: f i j (IxFree f j k a) -> IxFree f i k a

liftf :: IxFunctor f => f i j a -> IxFree f i j a
liftf = Free . imap Pure

instance IxFunctor f => IxFunctor (IxFree f) where
  imap f (Pure a)  = Pure (f a)
  imap f (Free fa) = Free (imap (imap f) fa)

instance IxFunctor f => IxMonad (IxFree f) where
  return = Pure
  Pure a  >>= f = f a
  Free fa >>= f = Free (imap (>>= f) fa)
  fail = error

-- Old stuff for Bake

type family New cs where
  New '[]       = 0
  New (c ': cs) = c + 1

type family Elem c cs :: Constraint where
  Elem c (c ': cs)  = ()
  Elem c (c' ': cs) = Elem c cs

type family Remove c cs where
  Remove c '[]        = '[]  
  Remove c (c ': cs)  = cs
  Remove c (c' ': cs) = c' ': Remove c cs

-- Now the return type indices of BakeF directly express the change
-- from the old store to the new store.
data BakeF cs cs' k where
  BakeF :: (Proxy (New cs) -> k) -> BakeF cs (New cs ': cs) k
  EatF  :: Elem c cs => Proxy c -> k -> BakeF cs (Remove c cs) k
  KeepF :: Elem c cs => Proxy c -> k -> BakeF cs cs k

deriving instance Functor (BakeF cs cs')
instance IxFunctor BakeF where imap = fmap

type Bake = IxFree BakeF

bake   = liftf (BakeF id)
eat  c = liftf (EatF c ())
keep c = liftf (KeepF c ())

ok :: Bake '[] _ _
ok = do
  cake1 <- bake
  cake2 <- bake
  eat cake1
  keep cake2
  eat cake2

-- not_ok :: Bake '[] _ _
-- not_ok = do
--   cake1 <- bake
--   cake2 <- bake
--   eat cake1
--   keep cake1 -- already ate it
--   eat cake2
```

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/FreeKitchen.agda) is the same, but with strictly-positive indexed free monads over indexed (only shapes are indexed) containers. I didn't include the `keep` constructor, since I'm not satisfied by the fact that `keep` doesn't change neither input nor output index. It seems to me that `keep` should exclude a cake from a context like `eat`, but include the cake in the output. My [original code](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/Kitchen.agda) does that,but I guess we need to double-index the `BakeF` functor then.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice and clean containers example (I haven't yet gotten around learning much about them).

Comment: And [the same](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/FreerKitchen.agda) using a [`Freer`](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/extensible/more.pdf) monad.

Answer (score 7):

Polakow showed in his Haskell Symposium paper [Embedding a full linear lambda calculus in Haskell (pdf)](http://functorial.com/Embedding-a-Full-Linear-Lambda-Calculus-in-Haskell/linearlam.pdf) how to do so.

The main idea is to index each constructor with an input and an output context tracking the resources consumed in the various subterms.

Answer (score 1):

A partial solution. We could define a wrapper type

```
data Caked a = Caked { getCacked :: IO a } -- ^ internal constructor
```

of which we do not export the constructor/accessor.

It would have two almost-but-not-quite-like-bind functions:

```
beforeCake :: IO a -> (a -> Caked b) -> Caked b
beforeCake a f = Caked (a >>= getCaked . f)

afterCake :: Caked a -> (a -> IO b) -> Caked b
afterCake (Caked a) f = Caked (a >>= f)
```

The only way for clients to create `Caked` values would be through:

```
eat :: Cake -> Caked ()
eat = undefined

keep :: Cake -> Caked ()
keep = undefined
```

And we would allocate `Cake` values on a callback:

```
withCake :: (Cake -> Caked b) -> IO b
withCake = undefined
```

This, I think, would ensure that `eat` and `keep` only get called once within the callback.

Problems: doesn't work with multiple `Cake` allocations and `Cake` values can still escape the scope of the callback (could  phantom types help here?)

Comment: ```withCake (\cake -> eat cake `afterCake` (\() -> withCake (\cake' -> eat cake)))``` looks like it eats `cake` twice (and `cake'` no times).

Comment: @Daniel Wagner You are right. Perhaps phantom type techniques à la ST monad could plug that hole.